# Exibir somente uma mensagem ao final de uma operação dentro de um WHILE

Tags: php, mysql, select, while

Tenho uma situação.
Faço uma busca em uma tabela e a partir dos dados retornados, insiro em uma nova tabela e atualizo a atual.
Ex:

```
$busca = $link->prepare("SELECT valor FROM tabela1 WHERE funcionario = ? and confere = 0");

$busca->bind_param("i", $funcionario);

$busca->execute();

$busca->bind_param($valor);

$busca->store_result();

if($busca->num_rows() == 0){
  echo "Nenhuma linha na primeira tabela";
} else {

  while($busca->fetch()){

    $novo_registro = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela2 (caixa) VALUES (?)");
    $novo_registro->bind_param("i", $valor);

    $novo_registro->execute();

    if($novo_registro == true){

      $update_tabela1 = $link->prepare("UPDATE tabela1 SET confere = 0 WHERE funcionario = ?");

      $update_tabela1->bind_param("i",$funcionario); 

      $update_tabela1->execute();

      if($update_tabela1 == true){

      echo "Ok<br>Debitado com Sucesso.";

      }else{

      echo "erro ao tentar atualizar a tabela 1";

     } // Esta chave fecha if($update_tabela1 == true){

    } else{

      echo "Oocrreu um erro ao executar a inserção.";

    } // Esta chave fecha if($novo_registro == true){


  } // Esta chave fecha o while($busca->fetch()){


} // Esta chave fecha if($busca->num_rows() == 0){
```

Ele está funcionando ok, entretanto estou tendo dificuldades com o retorno da mensagem

> Ok. Debitado com Sucesso.

Quando tenho MAIS DE UM registro na `tabela1`, a mensagem de sucesso aparece mais de uma vez por causa do `while($busca->fetch()){`.

[image: while_duas_vezes]

Como posso proceder nessa situação. Queria apenas um retorno final de sucesso ou falha, tipo assim:

[image: rsultado_esperado]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web, oque você pode fazer é usar uma variavél como auxiliar, siga este exemplo:

```
// variavél auxiliar
   $auxiliar = "";

// seu While
   while( $busca->fetch() )
   {
       if ( $auxiliar != $update_tabela1 )
       {
         // printa os dados
       }

     // aqui você atribiu o valor de $update_tabela1 para $auxiliar
       $auxiliar = $update_tabela1;
   }
```

Veja se isto funciona e se te ajuda. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
//código ocultado

$mensagem = ""; // declara essa variavel antes do while

//código ocultado

while($busca->fetch()){

//código ocultado

    if($update_tabela1 == true){
        $mensagem = "Ok<br>Debitado com Sucesso."; //atribui uma mensagem a ela
    }

//código ocultado


if(!empty($mensagem)){  //no fim do código você exibe a mensagem
    echo $mensagem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pesquisando eu pude encontrar uma solução. Me digam se ela é viável:

```html
while($busca->fetch()){

  if (!$i++){
 if($update == true){
   
   echo "Ok<br>Debitado com sucesso";
 
 }else{
  
   echo "Erro<br>Falha ao debitar";
 
  } // Esta chave fecha o if($update == true){
  
   }// Esta chave fecha if (!$i++){
 
} // Esta chave fecha o while aberto acima
```

Funcionou perfeitamente, mas é uma forma viável?